# Issue with parsing some elements out of a KML file

Tags: php, parsing, xpath, kml

I have an issue with trying to parse out bits of data using PHP from a KML file that I have generated and then sent to my webserver. I want to get the elements out, and store them to a database. Storing them isn't an issue, its just getting some elements out.

Here is en example of the KML file im trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>RandomName</name>
        <description>-</description>
        <Style id="line">
            <LineStyle>
            <color>CD0000FF</color>
            <width>4</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <ExtendedData>
            <Data name="StartTime">
                <value>1302653118875</value>
            </Data>
            <Data name="EndTime">
                <value>1302653159274</value>
            </Data>
            <Data name="Type">
                <value>cycle</value>
            </Data>
        </ExtendedData>

    <Placemark>
        <name>PlaceName2</name>
        <description><p>Current Altitude: <b>0.0 ft</b><br/>Current Speed: <b>0.0 m/s</b><br/>Total Distance: <b>0.608 km</b></p></description>
        <styleUrl>#line</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
            <extrude>1</extrude>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
            -122.083393,37.427768,0.0
            -122.084395,37.427768,0.0
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I am using the following code, and I am able to get out the very first name and description.

```
function getTrackDescription($file){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $namespace = $xml->getDocNamespaces();

    if(isset($namespace[""])){
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace("default",$namespace[""]);
    }

    $element= $xml->xpath('//default:description');
    return $element[0];
}
```

I am able to get these elements but when I attempt to get anything else, I just get nothing. I need to be able to access the values within ExtendedData - StartTime, EndTime and Type. I also need to get the description from Placemark.

I changed 1 line from the above code, in attempting to get the StartTime, but it doesn't work.

```
$element= $xml->xpath('//default:ExtendedData/Data[name="StartTime"]/value');
```

If anyone could help me out, or point me in the right direction I would be really greatful as I haven't really used XML to much.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `/kml/Document/ExtendedData/Data/value`...

Comment: As far as I can see, there are no namespaces in that file.  So why are you loading and configuring namespaces?  Why not just treat it as a normal non-namespaced document?

Comment: I think you should register the namespace URI `http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2` instead. It's not a good practice to rely on surce prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've defined a prefix for the namespace "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" you have to make sure that you use it for all elements falling into that namespace.  In the code above, you're essentially looking for `ExtendedData` with the prefix `default`, but then looking for `Data` elsewhere in a namespace with no prefix.

Here are your options:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
var_dump($xml->xpath("//ExtendedData/Data[@name='StartTime']/value"));
```

or

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("default","http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
var_dump($xml->xpath("//default:ExtendedData/default:Data[@name='StartTime']/default:value"));
```

Both should return the items that you're hoping for.